# Parallel JPA requests with `@Async` to boost performance?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, eclipselink

I am in charge of improving the performance of our application. I'm now at the point where I'm considering trying to making certain things run in parallel.

If it can help: we use Postgres as our DB, and EclipseLink is our JPA Provider.

This is a snapshot of a request's execution (against our `PUT /something` endpoint) as visualized through Dynatrace:

[image: PUT endpoint request on Dynatrace]

Each yellow bar represents an SQL query's running time in the DB.

Some of those calls are *not* dependent on each other and *could* happen simultaneously.

For example, considering the first 9 queries (from the first `SELECT` to the last `UPDATE`, inclusively):

1. The information from the `SELECT` queries is only used by the `INSERT` calls. They could thus be ran in parallel with the `DELETE` queries.
2. At the DB level, there are no Foreign Key constraints declared. This means I could run all the `DELETE` queries in parallel (and the same goes for the `INSERT` calls).

The question is: **what might be the reasons why I should avoid going down this route to optimize the performance of the endpoint by using `@Async`?**

I would use `CompletableFuture` as described in [Spring's `@Async` documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-async).

For example, potential pitfalls I have in mind:

- Thread management that might end up leading to poorer performance when the service is under stress load.
- `EntityManager` not being thread-safe.
- Exception handling.

The service expects a peak of 3000 requests/second, but this specific endpoint will only be called once every few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

On the database side, to run them in parallel would involve running them over separate connections in separate transactions, so you would lose the atomicity feature.  You could end up with some of them committing and some of them rolling back.

Also if your database doesn't have the resources to do multiple things at once, the different queries running at the same time might each run slower as they fight over the same resources, and so not actually be faster.